# Mongoose: How to avoid inserting duplicate records?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-directive, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have written the following mongoose function to create new document in mongodb

```
createdata: (body) => {
    let sEntry = new SData(Object.assign({}, {
        dataId: body.DataId
    }));
    return sEntry.save();
}
```

I want to modify the above logic so that it doesn't insert two rows with same `dataId`

In other words, if a particular value of `dataId` is already existing in mongo then it should not create another entry with same `dataId`

Comment: find by `dataId` to check if it's there?

Comment: can you help with the `find` query?

Comment: or put `unique: true` for `dataId` in your schema..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first install this [`mongoose-unique-validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator) for that. Then after you can define  `unique: true` in

In the second step, you need to define the `unique: true` in your schema. and also you have to handle the error response.

```
var SData = mongoose.Schema({
    dataId: { type: String, index: true, unique: true, required: true },
});

createdata: (body) => {
    let sEntry = new SData(Object.assign({}, {
        dataId: body.DataId
    }));
    return sEntry.save(function() {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

putting `unique: true` for `dataId` in the schema has resolved the issue